# ANSI escape sequences, how to enter escape character from keyboard?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, escaping

#### Problem:

- I recently found a page on changing the text colour in bash when echoing that was really helpful as it explained how to enter the escape as a single character through a sequence of key strokes. Unfortunately it was a school computer and the history was not saved. I have since not been able to find that page.

#### Question:

- If anyone knows the sequence of keystrokes to enter the escape character `^[` it would be much appreciated.

Comment: press: `CTRL-v` and after press `ESC` - but this far from the correct way. And, this is not really an programming question.

Comment: I considered it programming cause im using it as a way to echo escape sequences in bash scripts without having to call echo -e

Comment: @JamesC: You should probably ask the question in a more programming-oriented way, like "What do I put in my bash programs in order to output an ANSI escape sequence to the terminal?", as opposed to the question you asked which sounds like you want to know how to type hex character 1B. I answered the question I think you meant to ask.

Comment: @rici, why, exactly? If the question is on topic, the phrasing is reaelly just to please ---you--- criticasters. Then again, this is clearly a dupe. sadly, I can't find it. Grumble.

Comment: @sehe: i'm not on the list of close-voters, so the advice is precisely about how to avoid being criticast by those who do. Nonetheless, I do think the phraseology could be improved since OP means "output", not "enter"/input.

Answer (score 1):

The escape key can be generated with the backslash sequence `\e` in a command which interprets backslash sequences.

eg:

```
echo -e "Text can be \e[1;41mred\e[m or \e[1;45mmagenta\e[m"
for back in {30..37}; do
  echo -n $back:
  for fore in {40..47}; do
    printf "\e[1;%2d;%2dm%2d\e[m " $back $fore $fore
  done
  printf "\n"
done
```

A possibility not illustrated above is the bash escape interpreted string: `$'\e[1m'`.

---

Although using vt escape sequences (as above) is easy and supported by most if not all commonly-used unix terminal emulators, die-hards will insist that you learn to use the `tput` command:

```
 printf "Here is a %sbold red%s word\n" "$(tput bold)""$(tput setf 4)" "$(tput sgr0)"
```

IMHO, figuring out the magic tput symbols (see `man 5 terminfo` on a debian/ubuntu system) is not as easy as looking up the xterm control sequences (google the last three words), but YMMV.

Comment: There is a typo error in the example command: `$(tput setf 4)` -> `$(tput setaf 1)`

Comment: @Ippx: both should work identically unless your terminfo database is faulty, but `setf` is more die-hard (i.e.  older) than `setaf`. So it's not a typo; it was a deliberate choice.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I must be in the first case then, because `setf` has no effect.

Comment: @ippx: what os/distro/terminal emulator do you use?

Comment: Mint 19.2 (ubuntu 18.04 based) with Mate 1.22.0 Terminal